# Why is my raycast hitting the wrong object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, raycasting, physics-engine

I'm attempting to implement drag and drop functionality in a 3d Unity environment using a camera with Perspective projection.

The following code should generate a ray from the current mouse (eventually, touch) position to the object that appears to be below the mouse on screen.

```
private Ray GenerateMouseRay()
{
    Vector3 mousePositionFar = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.farClipPlane);
    Vector3 mousePositionNear = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane);

    Vector3 positionNear = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePositionNear);
    Vector3 positionFar = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePositionFar);

    Ray mouseRay = new Ray(positionNear, positionFar - positionNear);

    return mouseRay;
}
```

In my Update method, when mouse activity is detected, I am printing the name and coordinates for the object the ray hits. Once I get the ray to cast correctly, I will be able to implement drag and drop functionality.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //CalculatePosition();

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray mouseRay = GenerateMouseRay();
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(mouseRay.origin, mouseRay.direction, out hit))
        {
            hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
            objectPlane = new Plane(Camera.main.transform.forward * -1, hitObject.transform.position);

            Debug.Log(hitObject.name);
            Debug.Log(hitObject.transform.position.x + ", " + hitObject.transform.position.y + ", " + hitObject.transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:
Player
13.57, -8.5, 6.07

Actual Output:
OceanWaterArea
.5536325, -1.1, 1.218224

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: your player needs a collider for the raycast to impact. Is it the case?

Comment: I do have a rigid body and a collider on the player object.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by disabling collision on my water plane.

Comment: you may want to limit the objects you're trying to interact with by using a [LayerMask in your Physics.Raycast call](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)